# Извлечение данных с разных таблиц одни запросом. MySql

Tags: mysql, java-ee, select

Есть таблица юзеров. Есть таблица с данными этих юзеров. Подскажите как извлечь данные с таблицы юзеров и с таблицы данных юзеров одним запросом? Пишу на Java (JavaEE). При этом у этих таблиц есть свои `id` - автоинкременты. В таблице с данными есть ссылка на id юзера к которому принадлежат эти данные. Как вытащить эти данные по ссылке

Comment: `SELECT u.col1, u.col2, u.col3, ud.col1, ud.col2, ud.col3 FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_data ud ON ud.user_id = u.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в таком случае прибегают к многотабличному запросу, который организуется при помощи ключевого слова `JOIN`, например

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  d.*
FROM
  users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  users_data AS d
ON
  u.id = d.user_id
```

Т.е. у вас таблица пользователей `users` и таблица данных `users_data` с внешним ключом `user_id`, в котором находится `id` пользователя. В ключевом слове `FROM` вы при помощи оператора `JOIN` или `LEFT JOIN` задаете связь, условие связи задается в условии `ON`.

Comment: а что значит `AS u` ?

Comment: @Tsyklop Это псевдоним, чтобы сделать названия таблиц короче и не писать каждый раз users и users_data. Вместо users.id = users_data.user_id можно записать  u.id = d.user_id.

Comment: а. понял. благодарю.